How Can I Implement Custom Filtering for Supplier Dashboards in Superset?
I am currently working on a dashboard in Superset that displays information for my suppliers, and I'm having trouble with the filters. I've created a native filter with a list of my users, and I want each user to see only their relevant filtered dashboard when they access the application. For example, Supplier 1 should only see their clients and their information, while Supplier 2 should see their own data. After researching, I found out that achieving this directly is not possible. Can you propose an intermediate solution where I can store the users along with their respective filtered dashboards and consume this in the front of my Vue.js application? Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I expected that by applying the native filters, each supplier would be able to access their dashboard and see only their clients and associated information. Essentially, I wanted a seamless experience where the dashboard dynamically updates based on the logged-in supplier, providing a personalized view without exposing any irrelevant data from other suppliers.
